# In X3, will auto-aiming handle multiple weapon types?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict, x3-albion-prelude

In X3:Terran Conflict and X3:Albion Prelude, firing with auto-aiming via the left control key is excellent for offset shots against crossing targets while maneuvering.  However, it's not clear if auto-aiming can handle multiple forward gun types.

For example, if I mount forward concussion impulse generators and phased repeater guns, they will have visibly different offsets on the reticle and firing paths.  Is auto-aiming offsetting both weapon types against the movement of the target according to their shot speed?  Or am I sending fast shots down the same path as the slow shots (effectively ensuring a miss)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they won't unfortunately. Whatever part of the code does the calculation for the recticule will get confused and one sort of your weapons will miss.

What you can do, is having multiple groups, like 2x Weapon A and 2x Weapn B and then switch between them, so that only 1 Weapon Type is active. If you have more than 1 Weapon Type in your current group, it won't work, as already explained.

You might also look at this comment:

> http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?p=3093428#3093428

edit with another Source:

> http://forum.roguey.co.uk/viewtopic.php?id=460&p=1#3896

I may quote it for your convinience:

> well i cant anser the range question but i cant for the projectile
>   speed one,the auto aim will set the mark on the slowest weapon,so what
>   happends is that you're faster shots are in the same arc as the slower
>   ones.you end up wasting more energy this way though.here is an example
>   lets say you have some high energy plasma throwers paired with some
>   phased repeater guns,now you start shoting the first 50 shots of the
>   PRG will be wasted cuz they are shot to ahead of its target but shots
>   51+ are in the stream of the first few shots of the HEPT.

This matches my experience with the X Series.

Comment: Are you sure this is still true for AP?

Comment: Well, it is logic. Different weapons have different projectile speeds, which will result in different shooting angles for each weapon.

Comment: you are applying logic to a video game? :P
I'll have to test this later but its not impossible the game auto corrects for different projectile speeds

Comment: Added another source for my comment

Comment: +1 I just tested this in game with PBE and HEPTs (huge speed difference) it definitely did not auto aim both on the same target (the HEPTs tracked while the PBEs all missed)